# UISearchController cannot access tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a searchController on my screen

My problem is that when I type in to my tableview to tap a cell. the search controller is above the tableview and I cannot select the cell.,[image]

Init method

```
 self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)aSearchController {
NSLog(@"updateSearchResultsForSearchController");

NSString *searchString = aSearchController.searchBar.text;
NSLog(@"searchString=%@", searchString);

//    [self.moviesTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];


// Check if the user cancelled or deleted the search term so we can display the full list instead.
if (![searchString isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [self.filteredMovies removeAllObjects];
    for (FLMovie *movie in self.movies) {
        if ([searchString isEqualToString:@""] || [movie.title localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:searchString] == YES) {
            [self.filteredMovies addObject:movie];
        }
    }
    self.displayedItems = self.filteredMovies;
}
else {
    self.displayedItems = self.movies;
   }
    [self.moviesTableView reloadData];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the dimming background during presentation.

```
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
```